# How to give view permission in ASP.NET MVC application based on logged in User's Role

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, permissions

I'm new to ASP.NET MVC. I want some ideas regarding user role permission in views based on their role. For example, if user is a super admin only give add button enable /clickable permission, and for other users can able to view that window only.

Please any one suggest ideas.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: are you using Identity? Your question lacks detail of what you've tried and where you're stuck needing help

Answer (score 0):

set (if statements) in the view to add the buttons tags or just skip it , is this what you looking for ?

```
@{if((session["permissionAdmin"] != null ) && ((bool)session["permissionAdmin"])) 
    { 
        <input type="submit" id="Edit" \> 
    }
}
```